# Calling the event handler programmatically in an MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, event-handling

I am working on an MFC application (C++)

My checkbox has an event hander mapped to the `ON_BN_CLICKED`. 
It works fine when the user check/uncheck the box, i.e. the event handler is called.

However, when I check the box programmatically: `((CButton *)this->GetDlgItem(x))-> ->SetCheck(1);` the event handler is not called.

What should I do in order to call the event handler programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal behavior. The WM_COMMAND is sent when a "click" or "user entry" changed the button.

This is not contignous with child controls. Other child controls like an edit control also send a WM_COMMAND EN_CHANGE message when SetWindowText is executed by the program (the MFC blocks this message in a DoDataExchange).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question is how I can fire up the event handler in this case?

Comment: Just call the event handler directly. - OR - Send a WM_COMMAND message with BN_CLICKED and the appropriate infos in lParam/wParam. Just look into the MSDN for the format of WM_COMMAND.

Answer (score 2):

Try to [send BN_CLICKED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
this->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, 
MAKELONG(IDC_BUTTON1, BN_CLICKED), 
((CButton *)this->GetDlgItem(x))->GetSafeHwnd());
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me. I am sure all I needed was to tune your answer, but I'd rather to just call the handler directly as xMRi reminded me (simplicity!)